# PC won't boot with GPU connected

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, gpu

when I connect GPU to motherboard my PC won't boot even if I don't use of GPU output. There is no beep sound and etc. Just PC turning on but no boot.
If I disconnect GPU from board, PC will be boot.
Is the problem with PSU, GPU or motherboard or something else ? Thanks buddies.

Motherboard: asrock g41 vs3

GPU: gt 9600

Installed ram: 2*2

CPU: celeron LGA 775

PSU: farrassoo 430 watt real ( designed by hipro)

Comment: Have you verified that your GPU PCI-e is compatible with your motherboard? List your motherboard and GPU make and model - but if you can read up on the motherboard PCI-e compatible specifications and what your GPU is.

Comment: I had something similar with my GPU, I had to set the Legacy PCI mode to true, although that setting name will depend on your bios & motherboard manufacturer.

Comment: Voted to close as unclear because yoy did not bother to list the parts you are using.

Comment: @sajad , please improve your question to get better answers.  Remove the first irrelevant sentences.  Use good capitalization and commas.  Use two newlines to create new paragraphs.  Indicate precisely the make and models (missing Power Supply model at the time of this comment).  The PSU might not be able to provide enough power.

Answer (score 2):

Check the PSU specification. If possible try replacing it with a known good power supply.

The GT 9600 requires a 400W power supply (minimum), and a marginal or faulty power supply can give similar symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

Could also be a low-/wrong or not installed powerconnection to the gpu.

Comment: Explain more. Where is problem? PSU?

Comment: @busybyte, in this case, it would be better for the original poster to improve their question, before providing an answer.  After multiple edits, a premature answer migt no longer be valid.

Comment: O.t.: @wothwelle this what i tried many times, but only since a few minutes i'm able to comment . strange rules, but first i want to help or give intentions (like superuser helped me with a couple of issues) and in second i care about rules

Answer (score 0):

We don't know how big your power supply is, but it definitely sounds like what happens when your power supply isn't supplying enough power.  Get a bigger power supply and retest.

I would suggest 600w just to make sure you have enough.